# JSF toggle image on click

Tags: jsf-2

I need to toggle image between image1 and imange2 on-click. Also, I need to call a function (on-click) in myBean. I've tried with the following code, but it doesn't do anything, the image isn't clickable?

```
<h:graphicImage name="images/image1.png" action="#{myBean.toggleImage}" onclick="images/image2.png"/>


public void toggleImage() {
 // System.out.println();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can display images.

1. You use the name attribute along with the library attribute. In this case, JSF looks for the image in the images folder.

   `<h:graphicImage name="image1.png" library="images"/>`
2. You directly mention the image name .

   `<h:graphicImage value="/images/image1.png"/>`

The onclick attribute is a DHTML even attribute. You need to invoke a scripting function using that attribute. You cannot use an image path there.

What you need can be done using the following code.

```
 <h:commandLink action="#{bean.toggleImage}"> 
     <h:graphicImage value="{bean.image}"/>
 </h:commandLink>
```

You can set an image variable in the bean with image1, so the page loads with image1. When the image is clicked, invoke a method in the bean, which changes the value of image1 to image2.